# image processing filters for ios in openGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, opengl-es-2.0

I am searching for an iphone image processing filter which was similar used in `INSTAGRAM` with much efficient fast and best quality. I have searched for similar and found [Instagram Filters](https://github.com/diwu/InstaFilters) But it was unexpectedly deleted due to lack of license. Can any one has best idea or source for image filters which was used in Instagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a sample example of image filters in ios here
Find these project at:

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr

https://github.com/fguilleme/Filter

https://github.com/xissburg/XBImageFilters

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to checkout Brad Larson's excellent [GPUImage library](http://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). It contains lots of basic and advanced image processing functionality that enables you to create custom filters. Imitating the effects of Instagram's filters shouldn't be to difficult using the provided functionality, and there are lots of examples to get you started.

GPUImage uses OpenGL ES 2.0 for all processing so it should be very fast. According to the readme, uploading a frame from the camera applying a sepia filter and displaying it takes only 2.5 ms, as compared to 149 ms using Core Image.

Comment: Thank you will check out and get back to you